# What is fjappmgrbulk?

Tags: port, wireshark, packet, udp

I captured a udp packet from wireshark which ones port is 2510 and destination ip is 81.64.155.202. What is that port for? I found [this post](http://forums.cnet.com/7726-7585_102-548403.html?tag=posts;msg548403)) mentioning:

> "it's for fjappmgrbulk, fjappmgrbulk which is for a multicast UDP multimedia application."

But it doesn't seems that it is a multicast.

Comment: -1 All you had to do was google it, please read the FAQ...http://www.corrupteddatarecovery.com/Port/2510udp-Port-Type-fjappmgrbulk-fjappmgrbulk.asp

Comment: Did you read the title? I asked "What is fjappmgrbulk?" Which software? Who wrote it? Why do we using it for? What is the purpose? I read that link. It says that it is a virtual connection between two computers but WHY?

Comment: I thought this a spam on SU. :D

Comment: @Baran you posted no links to any research you did, you get answers and comments based on what prior research you did Before posting the question, READ THE SUPERUSER FAQ, no mention of the OS or what software you have installed either. Totally uninformed questions with few details tend to get poor answers and down votes here on SuperUser as per the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a networking application which does not respect IANA's list of reserved port numbers.

For example a malware author might deliberately use such a port.

Many applications can be configured by the end user to use any desired port.

Just because someone registered a port with IANA for multicast video doesn't mean that all uses of that port on the Intertubes are genuinely using it for the registered purpose.

Maybe it's malware sending you credit-card numbers back to a zombie at 81.64.155.202. Maybe it is something entirely innocent. Maybe it is some peer-to-peer application (torrent) uploading or downloading some video or audio data?

```
$ dig -x 81.64.155.202
202.155.64.81.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    PTR     81-64-155-202.rev.numericable.fr.
```

Looks like the destination is a PC belonging to a customer of a French ISP?